# Template not defined - Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I just started creating a Meteor app and added the `dburles:google-maps` package, I seem to have been following the steps he indicates in the tutorial of how to implement it, but I get the error `Template not defined`, my code is as follows:

**.html**

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>project-j</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Let's see where it takes us">
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, minimal-ui, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />
</head>

<body>
  {{> map}}
</body>


<template name="map">
  <div class="map-container">
    {{> googleMap name="map" options=mapOptions}}
  </div>
</template>
```

**.js**

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  GoogleMaps.load();
});

Template.map.helpers({
  mapOptions: function() {
    if (GoogleMaps.loaded()) {
      return {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.8136, 144.9631),
        zoom: 8
      };
    }
  }
});
```

Any ideas, I checked the finished repo and the code seems to be 1:1 with mine...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the client code either in a `/client` folder or wrapped in a check for `Meteor.isClient`:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) { 

    Meteor.startup(function() {...});

    Template.map.helpers({ ... });

}
```

If not, Meteor will run your code on the client ***and*** server, and Template is not defined on the server.

You can find more information about structuring your Meteor app at http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp